# SQL querying for a json field in a table on mysql v5.6.10

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I am trying to query for a column with json data in it. I couldn't find any `SELECT` statement that works for mySQL version 5.6.10.

Let's say we have a table called "dummytable". The column "details" have a json data and I am interested in 2 fields in that json.

`{"name": "John", {"school":{"name":"UCLA","id":23113"}}}`

I only want to extract "name" and "school name". I tried different mysql statements such as `JSON_EXTRACT` or `details:school:name` and none of them works on mysql 5.6.10

One example:

```
SELECT t.details:name, t.details:school:name
from dummytable t
```

If I run the query above I get a mysql error because this version of mysql doesn't support it.

*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':details:name, t.details:school:name
from dummytable t' at line 1*

Comment: The JSON datatype was added in 5.7. If you're using an earlier version, it's just a character string, you have to parse it in the client application.

Comment: @Barmar Is there any workaround that you may know of for parsing it into json within the SQL query? Thanks!

Comment: If your json is always in the same format, you can create your own function to extract values, but performance will be affected.

Comment: BTW, in the versions of MySQL that support JSON, the syntax would be `SELECT t.details->"$.name" AS name, t.details->"$.school.name" AS school FROM dummytable t`

Comment: Parsing it in SQL will be very difficult. You have to use things like `LOCATE(t.details, '"name": ')` to find that property name, and combine it with `SUBSTR()`. It won't be able to handle things like escaped quotes in the data with really complicated coding.

Comment: Is there any possibility you can do the query from a language like PHP or Python? Return the whole `details` string and use their JSON functions to parse it.

Comment: The workaround is to upgrade to MySQL 5.7, then you have JSON functions to extract fields. Really, don't fool around with parsing JSON in SQL. It's more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Also, why are you using MySQL 5.6.10 — that's from 2013! You should upgrade anyway. You're running a version with numerous security bugs.